# Russian language sites don't have Hot Network Questions, but the option to enable/disable it is still in user preferences

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, russian-stackoverflow, preferences

Most of SE sites have a Hot Network Questions block.

> [image]

[ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) doesn't, but still [has option](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9620/15479) to enable/disable this block in [preferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current).

> [image]

Could you remove this option from the preferences or enable a Hot Network Questions block for ruSO?

**P.S.** as I can see, it's not about international sites, [esSO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions) has this block.

Comment: It's not a per-site setting... it's network wide. So if someone just happened to try to disable it on their ruSO profile, they'd be out of luck. I don't see there needing to be special casing for this?

Comment: @Catija but why seSO has Hot questions block and ruSO doesn't?

Comment: I don't know but you're better equipped than I am to search meta ruSO to see if there's an explanation. And, if you can't find one, ask... and if you want it turned on, ask.