# Turn on Hot Network Questions list on Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, russian-stackoverflow

I've [asked about the HNQ option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335325/260198). [Comment from CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335325/russian-language-sites-dont-have-hot-network-questions-but-the-option-to-enabl#comment1102502_335325):

> I don't know but you're better equipped than I am to search meta ruSO to see if there's an explanation. And, if you can't find one, ask... and **if you want it turned on, ask**.

I've started [a discussion on our Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9675/15479). Our members want to see this list.

I've asked CMs in moderator chat to enable this list for us. I've sent a message to `team@stackoverflow.com` email. Asked after NY again.

I don't know where I should ask next...

A few comments:

1. It's about the HNQ list on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). We want to see this list on our site.
2. This is not about adding questions from ruSO to HNQ.

**P.S.**: On https://es.stackoverflow.com, for example, this list is enabled.

Comment: Nicolas responded to your meta request already. Can you please explain why his response wasn’t sufficient?

Comment: @Catija he didn't answer the question. His post is about "why we shouldn't include questions from ruSO to HNQ". But, as I said, we want to see the **list on our site**. This is **not about adding questions from ruSO to NHQ**. Also, he think that most of our users don't speak English.

Comment: It reads to me like he's answering your exact question and explaining it quite well... Essentially, since all of the HNQ content is in English and many (most) users on ru.SO do not speak English, we believe that adding a bunch of English content to your pages will add a lot of useless/frustrating noise. Users having the ability to disable it isn't sufficient - only logged in users have that option and most are unaware that it exists. At the very least this question needs to take those points into account and explain why they're invalid.

Comment: @Catija your reasoning makes sense to me, but could this issue be resolved by technical means - namely by inverting enabling / disabling logic? So that HNQ is disabled by default (including users who aren't logged in) and providing an option to enable it for registered logged in users

Comment: @Catija then why is this block enabled on esSO?

Comment: I’m not sure... and we might want to revisit that. But we’re not going to just say “it’s on for one site, we’ll turn it on for everyone”. We need a strong argument for what value it adds over the potential damage it causes **on your site**. Right now I’m not seeing that. We can check into options like what @gnat suggested but (from my limited understanding) we don’t have a site setting that allows it, which means we’d have to develop one, which could take months if it was determined to be something we want to pursue.

Comment: @Catija FWIW this approach can be used for _any_ non-English SO site, Russian, Spanish (why do you show HNQ over there btw?), Portuguese - and whatever other language you may want to add in the future

Comment: @Catija what **potential damage** could even be? It's just a small block in the sidebar.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica I (personally) find it quite frustrating to visit sites with content I can't read because they're in another language. It's also **not** a "small block" - on my screen it takes up the full height of the page (800px) on questions on my laptop - https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ3Sm.png The point of any FR is to explain why you need the feature - you haven't done that, instead insisting that we just give you what you want. Please - help us understand why this is helpful to have and how that outweighs the potential impact of English content on a non-English site.

Comment: You, in particular, have spent hours helping us find places where the UI isn't properly in Russian... and yet, here you are asking us to fill a chunk of your site with English content ... this confuses me.

Comment: @Catija: Your last sentence comes from pretty strange assumptions. The interface in mixed languages just looks ugly, unprofessional and leaves pretty lame impression, that's why we on ru.SO are so strongly bitten by the translation problems. We want a good translation not because we cannot read English. // Having a block of international questions is maybe not ideal from the puristic language point of view, but adds a lot of value for those who understand English. But having parts of the interface in English doesn't add value at all.

Comment: The potential downside of a slight annoyance to those who can't read English is dwarfed by the potential upside of exposing those who understand English to find interesting new questions all over the network. Judging by the scores of the question and the answers, the community has come to a clear decision.

Answer (score 17):

Okay. Reasons.

1. English is the lingua franca in every field. Russian developers are no exception, and a lot of them know English, so the information provided by Hot Network Questions is interesting for them.

   Saying that most Russian developers don't know English is disrespectful. RuSO exists not only for noobs who write their first "Hello, World!" program. It's for all Russian developers who prefer interacting in their own language, who wish to teach others and learn new things.
2. Hot Network Questions block isn't a mere ad. It's used by many users as a way to be active across the whole Stack Exchange network. Those who rely on it daily, have to go to another website just to see it.

   Having the block on every website is a matter of convenience and consistency. Again, RuSO isn't an isolated island for noobs who don't understand English. It's more than that.